# Changes saved in view are not updating in browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently updating the HTML in my views in an ASP.NET MVC application in VS2012 while running the application in debug.  However, when I save my changes in the view and refresh the browser, the changes do not appear.  Moreover, if I restart the application in debug mode or stop, make changes and restart the application, these changes still don't push to the browser.  Any suggestions on what's going on here as I know this should be working.

These are generally HTML changes, so for example, my code is:

```
<p>This is some Html</p>
```

This shows up in my browser. I then change the html

```
<p>This is some new Html that I changed and I want to see this change in my browser </p>
```

If I save this view and refresh the browser, the HTML/Page does not update

Comment: Please provide some code or be more specific about what the issue is.  If you are adding code to a view and it isn't showing up when navigating to that view, then it would be nearly impossible to assume what the issue is without seeing what you are trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact problem as yours and I just solved it. I had made a copy of another project that was in the same solution. I had made a copy of the original project directory, changed the name of the .csproj and .csprog.user files and then added this project back into the same solution. I wanted to experiment with changes to the original project while keeping the that one intact. The old project worked fine but the new copy did not.

I could change index.html in the original project and the changes would show up in the browser when I debugged. But if I did the same with index.html in the new copy, my changes would not appear in the browser when I debugged. But like you, if I just pointer a browser at index.html, I would see my changes.

The problem was that the port number of the new project was the same as the old. (http://localhost:59205/) See the project properties under the Web tab. I changed the port number and all was fine.

The cause of my problem not be the same as yours however.

Comment: This was the problem I was facing AND is the solution that we've been using.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem - and it turned out i had forgot to clear my web browser cache. A good workflow tip is to enable "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" in settings under chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, I forgot about an "OutputCache" attribute I used to decorate the action method of the controller:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 2000, VaryByParam = "*", Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```